# How to keep timer function running after seguing to a modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Basically I would like my timer to continue running a CheckMessage function in ParentViewController while allowing UI interaction in a modal ChildViewController which is segued by the ParentViewController.

I have tried using GCD (not good at it) but to no avail. Somehow when after the ChildViewController is pushed into view, the timer stops executing the said function.

Please help! Thank you so much...

Here is the code in ParentViewController:

```
NSTimer *timer_checkMessage;

-(void)viewDidAppear
{
    [timer_checkMessage invalidate];
timer_checkMessage = nil;

timer_checkMessage = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self    
    selector:@selector(CheckMessage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ChildSegue" sender:self];
NSLog(@"Seguing child view...");
}

-(void)CheckMessage
{
    //check message
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show some code? Btw: the tags ios and nsviewcontroller contradict each other.

Comment: Noted on the tags. The code is up there now...

Comment: (Note that you have not spelled viewDidAppear correctly!)

Comment: Ok. But I still need help conceptually!

Comment: Is there any other method in the view controller where `timer_checkMessage` is invalidated?